# bug in shared element in android Nougat

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have a strange bug in shared element. Seem like it only happens in my device, Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 with Android 7.
When I'm in Activity A, I have a shared element - a small picture that when click, it moves to Activity B and live in the center of the screen like in the picture, under that image, there will be a list of songs.
But sometimes the shared element doesn't work. It shows a transparent UI in Activity B, I can click the cover image to go to Activity C. When returning from Act C to B, it shows the error like in the picture. The loading indicator appears a lot. 
[image: Shared Element not working]

I don't know what to call this error. It sometimes happens and I don't know how to make the bug appear. Any hints?

Comment: put the code please

Comment: Did you check it with another device ?

Comment: @diegoveloper oh sorry, this project is private so I can't upload any codes.

Comment: @JavaBanana I've checked with other devices and it seems OK.

Comment: It's hard for someone to help. Could you explain more or post **snippet of code** that you guess the problem occurs from ?